# How do I test specific android application with CTS?

Tags: android, cts

I want test my application or specific apps with CTS but I can't find any way!!

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTS has nothing to do with testing your application. It has nothing to do with testing "specific apps". It is for testing an Android device build, for compatibility confirmation. This is used by device manufacturers (and, perhaps, by ROM modders) for confirming that changes they made to Android do not break any Android SDK APIs. Passing the CTS is a requirement for licensing the Play Store and other commercial apps.

For testing "my application or specific apps", you are welcome to use [the various test tools and frameworks in the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html).